# How to create a azure devops branch within a folder

Tags: azure-devops

Someone upgraded our TFS to Azure Dev Ops a couple of years ago. If I drill down one of the repositories in a project, there are dozens of folders some of which have branches within them. The icon I have boxed in red I assume is a branch:

[image]

I have created a brand new repository in DevOps via the browser interface, and while I have been able to create a few folders with projects, files, etc..., I cannot find a way to create a branch within a folder.

In Repo -> Branches, I see a New Branch button, but that branch will be created at the repo root. There does not seem to be a way to place a branch within an existing folder.

Is that correct? If not how can it be done? Perhaps via the command line somehow? Is this structure in the other repo because it was converted/imported from TFS?

Comment: The screenshot you posted appears to be from a TFVC repository. Is your new repository TFVC, or is it Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two version control systems available in Azure DevOps / TFS:

TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) and Git.

TFVC is a centralized version control system and is considered feature complete and no longer undergoing development. You can have **one** TFVC repo per Team Project. It supports folder-level branching within the repository. The screenshot you posted is from TFVC.

Git is a modern version control system. It is **fundamentally different** from TFVC on a deep technical level and **does not** support folder-level branches; branches are only at the repository level.

If you created a new repository within the team project containing your TFVC repo, it is, by definition, a Git repository.

The branches and merging strategies that you follow for TFVC and for Git are generally not interchangeable because of these core differences.

So to succinctly answer your question: You can't do what you want to do. If you are using Git, please look up common Git branching models such as GitFlow and GitHubFlow and choose one that is appropriate for your development scenarios.

Comment: @Mann , thank you for the reply. Correct we using TFVC in Azure Dev Ops, not Git.  Your answer is what I needed to know, so I can prep other developers into how we need to work now. It would be nice if that feature were available, but we will adjust.

Answer (score 6):

In Repo -> Braches

You could create new branches within an existing folder with the format:

Folder Name/Branch Name

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are assuming they are using Git. The screenshot they posted is from TFVC.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question, I wanted to ask. And I dislike the 'vote down' feature. It is a very negative aspect of SO; no pun intended :) So, I have rectified your -1 score for this answer :) You are now on a nice big zero! ;)